# C-statistic vs AUC

Tags: roc, auc, diagnostic

I am analysing diagnostic accuracy. I have a dataset with a ground truth and 3 predictors.

- Ground truth = binary (0/1)
- Predictor 1-2 = binary (0/1)
- Predictor 3 = continuous (0-100)

I have 50,000 observations, and each observation can maximum have ground truth = 1 once.

I have made ROC-curves with corresponding AUC-values for ground truth and predictor 1-3.

I have also made some subanalyses, where the definition of ground truth has changed a bit, and thus, it is here possible for the observations to have ground truth = 1 multiple times (yet, this is still rare).

My professor (who is not an statistics expert) has asked me to do the ROC-AUC curves for the main data (as I have done) and to perhaps include the c-statistics for the subanalyses.

My question is:
What is the difference between the c-statistic and the AUC? As far as I can read, it is basically the same?

- Perhaps the c-statistic take in mind that the outcome (ground truth) can happen multiple times?

I hope one of you are able to help me :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AUC in ordinal logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23992/auc-in-ordinal-logistic-regression) The first sentence of Harrell’s answer seems to confirm your suspicion that the concordance index for a binary outcome equals the area under the ROC curve.

Comment: The AUC and c-statistic are the same thing, unless perhaps you're doing something unusual and the setting in which they are the same thing does not apply. It's hard to understand the question `Perhaps the c-statistic take in mind that the outcome (ground truth) can happen multiple times?` because you haven't explained what it means for an outcome to happen multiple times -- AUC is most often used for binary outcomes, so the outcome is at most 1. Can you [edit] to explain what you're analyzing and how AUC and c-statistic fit into the analysis? What makes you doubt that they are the same?