# question on presenting multiclass classification results

Tags: machine-learning, pattern-recognition

I'm trying to figure out how to present results (e.g. precision, recall, accuracy, ROC curve) for a class project.

I have a multi-class classification problem(specific classification algorithm not really important) of classes **A, B, C and D**.

The classification algorithm was **trained** on **A, B and C**.

During the test phase, classification algorithm would determine unit test data to be **class A** if **likelihood_of_test_data >= likelihood_threshold_of_A** which is obtained in training phase.

Similarly classes B and C are also recognized in test phase.

If **likelihood_of_test_data < likelihood threshold of A, B and C**, it would be **recognized** as belonging to **class D**.

How can I draw the ROC curve in this case? Do I have to calculate precision and recall for each of the classes of A, B, C and D separately? Or I calculate just the accuracy?

Comment: or [How to compute precision/recall for multiclass-multilabel classification?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21551/how-to-compute-precision-recall-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification)