# I want to learn about ROC curve -- what is the canonical textbook?

Tags: r, classification, matlab, references, roc

I want to learn about Receiver-Operator-Characteristic curves, and metrics.  I have read through online webpages with some basics, and I have used MATLAB built-ins to create ROC plots.  It tells me about area sums.  I have also looked at the JMP module for classification and for Logistic plot which make ROC plots.

What is the canon here?  What is a great textbook with both deep fundamentals and worked out theory?  MATLAB and R are preferred.  Who made the field?  When?  Why?

I'm looking for good references.  Thanks.

Comment: The first thing is to learn when ROC curves are relevant/helpful.  I see them being used when it would be much better to use risk prediction.  They are not useful for determining a cutoff when a cutoff doesn't exist or when you are seeking a cutoff on an *independent* variable.  In general, ROC curves are at odds with individual decisionmaking.

Comment: @FrankHarrell I like your comment, what resources do you suggest?

Comment: ROC curves, instead of assisting with understanding, get in the way of understanding.  See the medical diagnosis chapter in BBR, link at http://www.fharrell.com/p/blog-page.html . There are two related articles on my blog fharrell.com .

Comment: @FrankHarrell, The resource behind the link has been moved. Would you mind mentioning the specific articles?

Comment: Sorry; it's now [here](http://hbiostat.org/doc/bbr.pdf).  The master page for all my links is fharrell.com/links.

Comment: Correct URL for all my links is https://hbiostat.org

Answer (score 5):

I would start from this practically canonical paper by Davis and Goadrich [The relationship between Precision-Recall and ROC curves](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1143844.1143874).

Through [this](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shavlik/roc.pdf), the ROC origins can be tracked to this book: [Evaluation of Diagnostic Systems:
Methods from Signal Detection Theory](http://www.bookfinder.com/dir/i/Evaluation_of_Diagnostic_Systems-Methods_from_Signal_Detection_Theory_Academic/0126790809/) which is unfortunately hardly accessible.

Comment: The paper asserts that P-R curves are less easily misinterpreted over-optimistically, but it says that description is outside the scope of the text.  Would you mind augmenting your answer with more material on P-R curves?

Comment: You didn't ask about P-R curves.