# How to find true positive, true negative, false positive, false negative from a three class confusion matrix?

Tags: confusion-matrix

I built a confusion matrix of three class. like, (a,b,c are the class)

```
-   a   b   c <= predicted
a   20  5   0
b   7  18   0
c   0   0  20
```

Now I want to calculate precision, recall from this confusion matrix. In order to do that I need to find out true positive, true negative, false positive, and false negative.

How can I find out the values of true positive, true negative, false positive, and false negative?

Comment: if you found one of the answers helpful pls. accept it - Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

When I understand your question correctly you are asking which class is the positive one and which is the negative one.

The answer is that this is to a certain extent arbitrary, so *you* have to decide that considering the problem at hand.

From ["Machine Learning with R" by Brett Lantz, 2.nd edition, 2015](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/machine-learning-r-second-edition), p. 318:

> The most common performance measures consider the model's ability to
>   discern one class versus all others. The class of interest is known as
>   the **positive** class, while all others are known as **negative**.
>
> The use of the terms positive and negative is not intended to imply
>   any value judgment (that is, good versus bad), nor does it necessarily
>   suggest that the outcome is present or absent (such as birth defect
>   versus none). The choice of the positive outcome can even be
>   arbitrary, as in cases where a model is predicting categories such as
>   sunny versus rainy or dog versus cat.
>
> The relationship between the positive class and negative class
>   predictions can be depicted as a 2 x 2 confusion matrix that tabulates
>   whether predictions fall into one of the four categories:
>
> • **True Positive (TP)**: Correctly classified as the class of
>   interest
>  • **True Negative (TN)**: Correctly classified as not the
>   class of interest
>  • **False Positive (FP)**: Incorrectly
>   classified as the class of interest
>  • **False Negative (FN)**:
>   Incorrectly classified as not the class of interest

This is the reason that you e.g. have to specify the positive class when using generic performance measure functions, like `ConfusionMatrix` in the [`caret` package in R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/).

Now another complicating factor is of course your multiclass setting, but this is answered here:
[How to compute precision/recall for multiclass-multilabel classification?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21551/how-to-compute-precision-recall-for-multiclass-multilabel-classification)

In general the most popular approach is to calculate these measures for each class by comparing each class level to the remaining levels (i.e. a "one versus all" approach).

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to merge the categories while calculating (e.g. $a$ and $\neg a$, where $\neg a$ is $b$ or $c$). True positive prediction for category $a$ is when $a$ was predicted and it was observed, true negative when it was not predicted and not observed, false negative when $a$ was observed but not predicted and false positive when it was predicted but not observed.

Comment: @Downvoter I would be happy to hear what exactly is wrong with this answer?

Comment: I couldn't find 3x3 confusion matrix on that wikipedia link. Only the 2x2 one.

Comment: @Unknown123 it must have been edited.